# Downgrade iOS 5.1 on my iPad to iOS 5.0

Tags: ipad, ios

New version of iOS is out & I have upgraded my iPad to iOS 5.1 from iOS 5.0. I didn't realize that some other software will not work with iOS 5.1 so I would like to go back. How can I downgrade iOS version on my iPad?

Comment: Our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) asks that all developer topics be asked on more code centric sites (or better on Apple's developer forums where NDA issues are not a concern.) I'm going to edit things so a consumer view question remains.

Answer (score 7):

Apple is still signing iOS 5.0.1. You will need to download the 5.0.1 ipfw and then place your device into DFU mode. From there, hold the ALT/OPTION key as you hit the restore button in iTunes. Then point iTunes to the newly downloaded firmware.

**You must act fast.** When Apple closes this window and stops signing the old firmware, it will not be possible to downgrade iOS.

Comment: As of Saturday March 10 the window seems to have closed. Either XCode or iTunes checks in with Apple after uncompressing the firmware, refuses to install 5.0.1 and trashes any 5.0.1 ipsw files.

Comment: @ErikOlson Thanks for the info. Apple moved fast on this one. So Srikar is out of luck it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is not easy route to accomplish a 5.1 to 5.0 downgrade even if you were to have a backup from a previous version. The upgrade process is typically one way. By upgrading you essentially lock yourself out of downgrading iOS to an earlier version. This is due in large part to Apple [imposed changes](http://www.ijailbreak.com/jailbreak/no-shsh-blobs-on-ios5/) and restrictions in iOS 5. You can Jailbreak your iPad which does offer other avenues for downgrading but at present there is no route from 5.1 to 5.0 that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade an iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad From iOS 5.1 To iOS 5.0.1 easily, just follow the guide in [this link.](http://jailbreak-untethered.com/how-to-downgrade-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad-from-ios-5.1-to-ios-5.0.1/)

Comment: dont want to jailbreak my device just to downgrade. IS there any way to downgrade without jailbreaking?